# Gthumb version 3.8 (or later) crashes resizing jpg on Ubuntu 20

Tags: 20.04, xfce, crash, gthumb

my first post here, so bear with a newbie ;)

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS with XFCE.
My system is up-to-date (sudo apt-get update/upgrade)

I have been using **Gthumb** for years without problems. Since a couple of weeks it crashes when I try to resize a picture (jpg). The latest version of Gthumb in the standard repositories is 3.8.0.
I uninstalled and installed again to no avail. Later I managed to upgrade to 3.9 and now even 3.12.0 via this page:
https://ossmalta.eu/gthumb-3-12-0-released-how-to-install-via-ppa-in-ubuntu-20-04/

I started gthumb from the terminal to see what kind of info would show up:
What I did was:

1. start gthumb
2. open a picture (jpg) (whatever, fault with every picture I tried)
3. click on tools--> resize
4. ** bang ** program disappears and throws error as show below

```
$ gthumb

** (gthumb:22679): WARNING **: 17:44:54.779: _cairo_image_surface_create: could not create the surface: invalid value (typically too big) for the size of the input (surface, pattern, etc.)

** (gthumb:22679): CRITICAL **: 17:44:54.779: _cairo_image_surface_copy_metadata: assertion 'dest != NULL' failed

** (gthumb:22679): CRITICAL **: 17:44:54.779: _cairo_image_surface_get_metadata: assertion 'surface != NULL' failed
Segmentation fault
```

Here I read about the/a similar error (cairo surface related) also being an security issue on Debian, dated 21th of august:
https://www.debian.org/lts/security/2021/dla-2749.en.html

On this gitlab page there is mentioning about a fix (one month ago!) that is also Cairo surface related:
https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gthumb/-/commit/3d985d64492d102027fff41b33be391eb450a6de

All this still does not bring me closer to a solution. I can not find anything when I search for, for example :"gthumb crash resize"

Any help or clues highly appreciated. I you want additional info on my setup/system, please ask.
I'm not a developer or an expert, but a reasonable experienced Linux user.

Thanks

Otis

Edit: corrected a typo Ubuntu 20.04.2 changed into 20.04.3
Edit 2: I **have** uninstalled and installed gthumb 3.8.
Edit 3: A bug report has been filed now as well

EDIT 4: I managed to take a screenshot *just* before Gthumb vanishes(crashes) , just after clicking 'resize'

[image: Gthumb screenshot just before crashing...]

As you can see the 'height' of the picture has absurd size (157933 pix.) and the aspect ratio is accordingly.... I don't know what comes first, the aspect ratio followed by calculated size or vice-versa.

QUESTION: I would like to know where Gthumb stores its preferences to see if there is a preference saved previously that causes this absurd aspect ratio for example

Comment: This sounds like a bug and you should [file a bug report](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).  In the meantime, try to uninstall and reinstall the software.  I would remove the PPA since it is more likely to be less stable than the version in Ubuntu repositories. You might also want to clear user data by removing any configs specific to gthumb in your user's home folder. Ex. `~/.config/`

Comment: You are also behind in updates it should be 20.04.3 run update and upgrade.

Comment: @Nmath : I will see if I manage to file a bug report. In the mean time I'll follow your recommendations and report back if it changes for the better